# Is it good practice to consume Login functionality from .NET Core API by storing tokens in HttpContext.Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a .NET Core 2.0 Restful API, which has login functionality enabled with openiddict and JWS tokens. I also have a .NET Core Web App that consumes the API. Currently I am using `HttpContext.Session` on the client side to store and get the tokens in order to login the users. Since I am fairly new to .NET Core I wanted to ask if this is a good way to implement login functionality and if not how should I do it?

WebAPI AuthorizationController

```
    [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        Debug.Assert(request.IsTokenRequest(),
            "The OpenIddict binder for ASP.NET Core MVC is not registered. " +
            "Make sure services.AddOpenIddict().AddMvcBinders() is correctly called.");

        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

            var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var loginRole = request.GetParameters().ElementAt(3).Value;

            if (user == null || userRole.ElementAt(0) != loginRole)
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                });
            }

            // Validate the username/password parameters and ensure the account is not locked out.
            var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                });
            }

            // Create a new authentication ticket.
            var ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(request, user);

            return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
        {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
            ErrorDescription = "The specified grant type is not supported."
        });
    }
```

WebApp AccountController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokenDetails = null;

                var fullUrl = _appSettings.Value.Apis.GSRTCApi.Url + _appSettings.Value.Apis.GSRTCApi.LoginEndpoint;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(fullUrl)
                };
                var login = new Dictionary<string, string>
               {
                   {"grant_type", "password"},
                   {"username", vm.Email},
                   {"password", vm.Password},
                   {"role", vm.Role}
               };
                var response = client.PostAsync("Token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(login)).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    tokenDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    if (tokenDetails != null && tokenDetails.Any())
                    {
                        var tokenNo = tokenDetails.ElementAt(2).Value;
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenNo);

                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", vm.Email);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Token", tokenNo);

                        //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                        return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return PartialView("../Account/_Login", vm);
    }
```

Comment: Please add code samples that pinpoint what you are asking.

Comment: The question is general, can you please specify a scenario or provide us with a code snippets

Comment: take a look at https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/

Comment: I have included code snippets, let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me if it  is a good idea to store access token in HttpContext.Session, and if not where should I do that?